# Dynamic spacing between items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have horizontal RecyclerView with 10 items with square fixed size and with attached LinearSnapHelper.
I want to see an integer number of items in the list depending on the width of the RecyclerView.

Example:

[image]

I think that I have to somehow calculate the width of the RecyclerView and find how many whole items will fit into the visible part of the list, and the remaining space should be reserved for spacings between items. After that, user scrolls items with SnapHelper. Thanks in advance for help!

**EDIT:**
I do not want to show all the items from the list at a time, but only those that fit into the visible area of recyclerview and calculate spacings dynamically between items

Comment: Just a quick thought, wouldn't it be better to use a ViewPager that displays N results per "page" ? (talking about less measure calculation and simplicity)

Comment: what you can do it to get the width of the screen and 1 item (I guess it has fixed width). then check how much space is left and pass it to the recyclerView Adapter. apply that space as margin in bind view method.

Comment: But user will not be able to scroll them, if all items are visible on the screen. If you need scrolling while all items are visible, you need to add invisile items at the end and the beginning of the list

Comment: I'll look for a solution with viewpager, but I think that the recyclerview is needed here.
I don’t want to calculate everything manually, there must be another solution.
I do not want to show all the items from the list at a time, but only those that fit into the visible area of recyclerview and calculate spacings dynamically between items